# Android title bar icon being cropped

Tags: android, icons

The edges of my icon are being cropped when viewed in Android's equivalent of the alt-tab menu.

[image: Cropped icon]

There should be a thick solid white border around the whole edge. It appears perfectly around the rest of android.

I've noticed this happen with a few other icons I've created as well. How can I fix it without affecting how the icon is displayed elsewhere?

Here is the original SVG that I imported (minus the inner boxes)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg8"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 141.565 141.565"
   height="141.565mm"
   width="141.565mm"> 
  <g
     id="layer7">
    <g
       transform="translate(-34.2175,-77.7175)"
       id="g6440">
      <rect
         style="opacity:1;fill:#222222;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:14.56499958;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="rect4487"
         width="127"
         height="127"
         x="41.5"
         y="85"
         rx="19.020206"
         ry="19.020206" />

      <!-- ...inner boxes... -->
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Generated XML from Android studio...

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="141.565"
    android:viewportWidth="141.565" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillAlpha="1" android:fillColor="#222222"
        android:pathData="M26.303,7.282L115.262,7.282A19.02,19.02 0,0 1,134.283 26.303L134.283,115.262A19.02,19.02 0,0 1,115.262 134.283L26.303,134.283A19.02,19.02 0,0 1,7.282 115.262L7.282,26.303A19.02,19.02 0,0 1,26.303 7.282z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1" android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="14.56499958"/>
...
```

**Update**: I tried shrinking the icon size by increasing the viewPortWidth/Height attributes and got this.

[image: Shrunk icon]

It seems like there is a mask/border there by default. Any idea where this may have come from and how I can get rid of this?

Comment: how you add icons in Android studio?

Comment: @AsadAli res > drawable > right click > new > vector asset then import from a local svg

Comment: its added in drawable folder or mipmap?

Comment: Drawable. I've added the generated XML to the original post as well

Answer (score 0):

set this attribute in Image view u used this svg

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: Tried this and variations of the scale attribute and it didn't help. Updated my original post to show what happens when you make the icon mini, it seems like there is a mask there that's the problem as oppose to the icon scaling itself.

Comment: Ok I guess it's this https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive